# Is it possible to adjust the leading on a font?

Tags: fonts, font-face, webfonts

I'm using a font which, for some reason, floats above the baseline compared to other fonts. I want to convert it to a webfont and embed it using @font-face but I need a way to either repair the font, or somehow correct the strange leading with CSS. Is this possible?

Comment: Is this a problem with the font itself or in your CSS? To convert fonts, there are many sites that are available however you have to ensure you are entitled to its copyright. http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was slightly mistaken in my original question, because I was converting from cufon.js to using @font-face. The rendering was a little wacky due to the cufon rendering (not the actual font or the css). Nevertheless, in the course of figuring this out, I think I came up with useful answers:

1. To make adjustments to the actual font, the go-to (open-source) tool for this job seems to be: [fontforge](http://fontforge.org/). The interface is clunky, but it's a powerful tool if you can figure out how to use it. Newer Macs will need to install XQuartz (or another X11 environment) to run it.
2. As for adjustments to the css/webfont, [font squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) seems to offer the most powerful generator with the most customizable options, such as ex-height matching and character subsetting, and a bunch of other advanced options that are over my head. The downside is that many font foundries have requested their fonts to be blacklisted so the generator won't convert them for copyright reasons.

Between these two tools, and familiarity with css3 font styles, you should pretty set-up for web typography today.

ps: I know of many alternatives to fontsquirrel that seem to do pretty much the same thing with less options. But I don't know any reasonable alternatives to fontforge. Please feel free to comment with alternatives if you know of any.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can change leading on a font in CSS is by using `line-height:12px;` which is set as default to the font size (depending whether you've also changed the `font-size` in CSS. You can go into minus numbers but am unsure whether that will look any good!

The other alternative is using `margin` and `padding` within the `p` tag or whatever tag it is nested in.

I believe WebKit browsers have a very nice styling, `-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;` which helps create a smoother font.

If you're talking about the look of the font, rather than the leading, you might be running into an IE issue where the @face-font imports are very 'jagerdy'.

I've come across this issue quite a lot, especially using light fonts. You can check against this in compatibility mode and see if the font is fixed. If this is not the case then only your font is the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the css "letter-spacing" property adjusts kerning, not leading. Leading is vertical height, which has a corresponding css property "line-height" (don't ask me why css doesn't use the proper typography terms).

Comment: Ah, apologies - I meant `line-height`, I get those two mixed up all the time due to lack of typography terms.

Comment: If you're still having trouble, could you send over a link or a JS fiddle so we can help further?